# Add xsi:type to element when using ... for xml explicit, root('ArrayOfEventItem')

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I create some XML in SQL Server with:

```
select 
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,    
    a.Start as [EventItem!1!StartTime!Element],
    a.[End] as [EventItem!1!EndTime!Element],
    a.ResId as [EventItem!1!ResourceId!Element],
 from
    Activity a 
 for xml explicit, root('ArrayOfEventItem')
```

The result is:

```
  <EventItem>
    <StartTime>2012-08-16T08:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime>2012-08-16T17:00:00</EndTime>
    <ResourceId>3</ResourceId>
  </EventItem>
  <EventItem>
    <StartTime>2013-06-06T08:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime>2013-06-06T17:00:00</EndTime>
    <ResourceId>4</ResourceId>
  </EventItem>
```

But I also need the type information in the result - it should be:

```
<EventItem>
    <StartTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2012-08-16T08:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2012-08-16T17:00:00</EndTime>
    <ResourceId xsi:type="xsd:int">3</ResourceId>
</EventItem>
<EventItem>
    <StartTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-06-06T08:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-06-06T17:00:00</EndTime>
    <ResourceId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ResourceId>
</EventItem>
```

How can I add this (the `xsi:type=""`) to my select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi )
select 
    1 as "Tag",
    NULL as "Parent",    
    'xsd:dateTime' AS "StartTime/@xsi:type",
    a.Start as "StartTime",
    'xsd:dateTime' AS "EndTime/@xsi:type",
    a.[End] as "EndTime",
    'xsd:int' AS "ResourceId/@xsi:type",    
    a.ResId as "ResourceId"
 FROM
    Activity a 
 FOR XML PATH('EventItem'), ROOT('ArrayOfEventItem')
```

Comment: @BennoDual 1.5 years :)